# mysql database problem now I can't reach to the database

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy

[image: 1]

this my actual problem can somebody help I was developing website using python flask framwork  and now I facing issue to fill the form of my page in mysqldb error I have tried to install mysqlclient but can't install it

Comment: Table icecode. contacts doesn't exist. Hence dig into it. You try INSERT INTO contacts, but it cannot insert into the table because: You don't have the SCHEME.TABLE or You have the scheme, but not this table. Just check it twice.

Comment: Just to prove what he said, try this:
SELECT * FROM icecode.contact;
If that fails as well, your table doesn't exist, so if it SHOULD exist, then you connection issues or something preventing you from seeing that db.